# Supporting a dev and auto-built prod branch via github actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to put together a repo in GitHub that supports 3 things.

1. Developers work in a dev branch, contributing via pull request.
2. A production-ready branch is compiled from the dev branch, ideally semi-automatically with appropriate version strings. (To be consumed by Composer, etc.)
3. Repo produces a production-ready release (zip file) with appropriate version strings.

I'm struggling the most at #2. So far my full monolithic (which is incidental at this point) action looks like this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

permissions:
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write

name: release-please

jobs:
  release-please:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: google-github-actions/release-please-action@v3
        id: release
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_TOKEN }}
          release-type: simple
          package-name: release-please-action
          extra-files: |
            arbitrary.file
```

Here I'm using Google's [release please](https://github.com/googleapis/release-please) with conventional commits to track version progression. The library will create pull requests on push to `dev` and maintain version numbers in any `arbitrary.file`s. So developers create pull requests, release please continually compiles them into a release pull request until such time as you merge it.

```
      - name: Checkout dev
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: dev
      - name: Install Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      - name: Build
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
      - name: Checkout prod
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: main
      - name: Create PR on main
        if: ${{ steps.release.outputs.release_created }}
        id: cpr
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v5
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_TOKEN }}
          branch: main
```

This is where I'm awkwardly trying to address #2 via the [create-pull-request action](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request). I am failing utterly here. The conditional informs the action if a release was created, which is the only time we want it to run.

```
      - name: Upload
        if: ${{ steps.release.outputs.release_created }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: gh release upload ${{ steps.release.outputs.tag_name }} ./build/archive.zip
```

Here we're just grabbing some compiled assets sitting in a zip and uploading it to the release, which also only occurs conditionally.

Maybe I need to go back to the drawing board, maybe I need to automate less? Ultimately I need as little human work here as possible, which I tried to address by only needing someone to review pull requests. Maybe I'm coming at this issue wrong.